# Filling the screen with data from several observables

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have a screen that is populated by an object returned from firestore, but I can not return the data of two queries on the same onInit

Service:

```
      export class TcpService implements MPersist{
      tcpsO: Observable<TcpID[]>;
      private tcpCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Tcp>;
      constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

      addDoc(data: Tcp) {
        this.tcpCollection.add({ nome: data.nome, nivel: data.nivel, registro: data.registro })
      }
      editDoc(data:TcpID){
        this.tcpCollection.doc(data.id).set({ nome: data.nome, nivel: data.nivel, registro: data.registro })
      }

      removeDoc(id){
        this.tcpCollection.doc(id).delete();
      }

      getDocs() {
        this.tcpCollection = this.db.collection<Tcp>('tcps');
        return this.tcpsO = this.tcpCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Tcp;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data }
          }))
        );

      }
    }
    export interface TcpID extends Tcp { id: string }
```

And for component:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        return this.service.getDocs().subscribe(
          res => {
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.dataSource.data = res;
          }
        );
      }
```

So I can manipulate the data, but when I try to return 2 different queries does not work, I need to fill the component with information from 2 different queries

Comment: you can use combineLatest or forkJoin observable operators, depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

When using DataSources it is recommended to set a new DataSource when changing data. So basically something like:

```
this.dataSource = new DataSource(res)
```

could fix your problem.